# apache shiro url config for path variable

Tags: shiro

I have a spring controller like following:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/tickets")
public class TicketWeb {

    @GetMapping("/{ticketNo}")
    ...

    @GetMapping("/a")

    @GetMapping("/b")

    @PostMapping("/c")

    //maybe more fixed path mapping
}
```

In this controller, I have one `path variable` like `/{ticketNo}`, others are fixed path.

With apache shiro, I want `annon` for path variable only, all other fixed path are `authc`.

According to apache shiro doc, it seems that there are only two solutions to achieve my goal:

**option 1** is :

```
filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/tickets/a","authc");
filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/tickets/b","authc");
filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/tickets/c","authc");

filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/tickets/*","annon");
```

that is set `fixed path` to `authc` one by one explicitly, set `path variable` to `annon`, but this is not good because maybe there are some `fixed path` or add more `fixed path` in future.

**option 2** is change path variable `/{ticketNo}` to another, e.g. `/annon/{ticketNo}`, to distinguish fixed path, such that developer can set

```
filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/tickets/annon/*","annon");

filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/tickets/*","authc");
```

with only two lines.

So there are only these two solutions to implement my goal, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Shiro uses Ant-style pattern matching, see: https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.5.0/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/util/AntPathMatcher.html for some examples.

Comment: yes, I checked the official doc, but it seems that I have to change the path in order to achieve my intend, that is `option 2` in my post, right?